# Import from .tsv with provided index

Tags: mongodb, csv, import, unique-index

I would like to import data to a MongoDb document from a `.tsv` file using the record _id as defined in my file.

How would I go about using the _id as specified in my `.tsv`, specifying the MongoDb should use the provided _id rather than generating its own?

Example data set:

`student firstName lastName
ab867499 example   student`

I want MongoDb to use the student column as _id rather than generate its own object_id as the key.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question a little. You are not really talking about a MongoDB index or a file that contains an index here but rather an _id field! Indexes are a completely different concept and unrelated to your question.

Comment: @dnickless thanks for the suggestion, question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
mongoimport --db <your_db_name> --collection <your_collection_name> --type tsv --file <path_to_file> --fields _id,firstName,lastName
```

In this case you will want to make sure that the first line of your file does not contain the header row or simply drop the imported document for the header row after the import.

Also, make sure you have a line break at the end of your last line of data in your file since `mongoimport` will skip this last record otherwise.